# Button click event is firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

so I have a problem with this buttons firing multiple times. If i click one button it works fine (tis firing only once) but if i click right after another button, it will fire twice and so on. I tried the .of("click") , $(this).unbind() and .one("click" , function(){}) methods but they didnt work. Please help me I really need help. Thank you in advance!

```
   $("#submitMember").on("click",function(){

    alert("Member submited!");

    //pull the data from the inputs
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#memberName").val();
    var email = $("#memberEmail").val();
    var adeziune = $("#adeziune").val();
    var address = $("#memberAddress").val();
    var job = $("#memberJob").val();
    var jobPlace = $("#memberJobPlace").val();
    var memberCNP = $("#memberCNP").val();

    //checking if all the inputs had benn filled
    if(firstName=="" || lastName=="" || email=="" || adeziune=="" || address=="" || job=="" || jobPlace=="" || memberCNP == "") {
        alert("Va rugam sa completati toate campurile !");
    } else {

        //send the request to members_script.php
        $.ajax({
            url: '../php_scripts/members_script.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                memberSubmited: 1,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                adeziune: adeziune,
                address: address,
                job:job,
                job_place: jobPlace,
                memberCNP: memberCNP
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#memberTableBody").html(response);
            },
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    }
    $("button").unbind();
});

//submiting  the post
$("#submitPost").on('click', function(event){
    //preventing the form submision
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Post submited!");

    var imageName = $("#postImage").val();
    var postTitle = $("#postTitle").val();
    var postAuthor = $("#postAuthor").val();
    var postTags = $("#postTags").val();
    var postCategory = $("#selectCategory").val();
    var postContent = $("#postContent").val();

    var image = imageName.replace(/^.*\\/, "");

    //chcking if the fields are filled
    if(postTitle == "" || postAuthor == "" || postTags == "" || postCategory == "" || imageName == "" || postContent == "") {
        alert("Va rugam sa completati toate campurile!");
    } else {

         $.ajax({
            url: '../php_scripts/post_script.php',
            method:'POST',
            data: {
                postSubmited: 1,
                postTitle: postTitle,
                postAuthor: postAuthor,
                postTags: postTags,
                postImage: image,
                postCategory: postCategory,
                postContent: postContent,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("#postsTableBody").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            },
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    }
    $("button").unbind();
    alert("Unbinded");
});
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion, create a minimally reproducible example on a site like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).  It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: hard to say without seeing more of your code. Firing multiple times usually means you registered event handlers to the same element more than once.

Comment: In your code, `$("button").unbind()`, unbinds all the buttons in the document immediately. Are you sure it is the intended behavior?

Comment: It's probable that you're binding the `.on()` event somewhere else (or the some reloading is firing the script again). One solution is to do `$(...).off().on('click'....)`, which works fine most of the time unless you have other events bound that you need to keep. If it's just the click event, then it's safe to use.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9h0ck36x/ shows that `unbind()` works exactly as intended. All buttons are disabled after one of them is clicked. You need to look elsewhere in your code to track this problem.

Comment: @jrook that's making assumptions about the markup. What if `#submitPost` is outside `button` and we're dealing with bubbling events: https://jsfiddle.net/801zLq5r/  ... in other words, we need to see the html as well.